# Is it more efficient to run a Node JS application through CRON at set times, or to run a 24/7 Node Application utilizing CRON inherently?

Tags: node.js, cron

Is it more efficient to run a Node JS application through CRON at set times, or to run a 24/7 Node Application utilizing schedulers inherently?

Option A:

- CRON Job for daily process - calls daily NodeJS App
- CRON Job for weekly process - calls weekly NodeJS App
- Advantage is the application only runs when it needs to.
- Disadvantage is overhead and organization.  You are required to have separate projects/scripts for each different action.

Option B:

- Separate NodeJS application which runs 24/7.
- Calls it's daily operations daily, weekly operations weekly, etc.
- Advantage: One project containing all CRON rules - easy to add more tasks
- Disadvantage: Project must be running 24/7, more overhead when not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at daily and weekly frequency only, I would go for a CRON job that calls your NodeJS app. If that task runs in 5 minutes, you will only have CPU and RAM utilisation during those minutes, instead of having a full NodeJS app staying in memory and using CPU resources all day (although minimal).

You don't need two directories; you can only have one directory where you have a daily.js job file and a weekly.js file. Or you could even have 1 single file (index.js) and call it with an argument to trigger the daily or weekly job.
In your index.js you would need to read the [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) array to read the argument that was passed in.

The index.js code would look as follows:

```
if (process.argv[2] == "D") {

  //code for daily task

} else if (process.argv[2] == "W") {

  //code for weekly task

} else {

  throw new Error("Invalid argument");

}
```

And your crontab file would look like this (to run the daily job at 3am every day and the weekly job at 6am on Monday for example):

```
0 3 * * * node /path/index.js D
0 6 * * 1 node /path/index.js W
```